# gt table how to add a border to column by spanner column label?

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

I wanted to add a border to the left of a group of column with the same column label spanner and i dont know how to do it !

I try this :

```
%>%tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_borders(
        sides = "left",
        color = "black",
        weight = px(3)
      )
    ),
    locations = cells_column_spanners(everything()))
```

but it only add border on the column spanner label part and not the entire column.

have you any idea how to do it ?

I have the result on the top and i want the result of the bottom :
[image]

Thanks for your help !

data for example (the gt format gives a lot of lines and i cannot put them here):

```
x<-structure(list(A = c("1", "2", "3"), 
                                        `ONE||N` = c(0, 0, 0), `ONE||%` = c(0, 0, 0), `TWO||N` = c(0, 
                                                                                                   0, 0), `TWO||%` = c(0, 0, 0), `THREE||N` = c(0, 0, 0), `THREE||%` = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0), `THREE||Δ` = c(0, 0, 0), `FOUR||N` = c(0, 0, 0), 
                                        `FOUR||%` = c(0, 0, 0), `TOTAL||%` = c(0, 0, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the data using `dput` to recreate the problem. And also, add the expected output.

Comment: I add a picture to explain my problem @VishalA.

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem. Please add data.

Comment: How can i add a file to my question ? The structure of the data is too big , I have to much line !

Comment: Let's say you have the data frame with the name `df`. All you have to do is run `dput(df)`. And paste the output here in your question.

Comment: I think i put what you want ! sorry !

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by first creating variables:

```
last_col_spanner <- "Horror" 
first_col_spanner <- "Drama"
g() %>%tab_style(
style = list(
  cell_borders(
    sides = "left",
    color = "black",
    weight = px(3)
  )
),
locations = cells_body(last_col_spanner)) %>%
tab_style(
style = list(
  cell_borders(
    sides = "right",
    color = "black",
    weight = px(3)
  )
),
locations = cells_body(first_col_spanner))
```